# Go language simultaneous assignment through un-buffered channel: how does it work?

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and saw this program at [go.dev/tour/concurrency/2](http://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
    go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

I recall that in python the execution flow of `a, b = b, a` should be like:

> 1. Create a temporary tuple of (b, a)

> 2. Assign each value in (b, a) to variables in (a, b) with a loop

The method doesn't seem to apply to this occasion in GO. So what actually happens in that `a, b = b, a` sentence?

Comment: There is no `a, b = b, a` style assignment, the variables on the left are different from the one in the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a, b = b, a` is an assignment, more specifically a tuple assignment.

It is detailed in the [Spec: Assignments:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignments)

> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued operation to a list of variables.
>
> [...]
> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of [index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and the expressions on the right are all [evaluated in the usual order](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation). Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.
>
> ```
> a, b = b, a  // exchange a and b
> ```

So first the (current) values of `b` and `a` are read, then they are assigned to `a`, `b`, effectively swapping their values.

This:

```
x, y := <-c, <-c
```

Is a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), it is equivalent to a regular [variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) with initializer expressions but no types:

```
var x, y = <-c, <-c
```

This will receive from `c`, twice, and assign the received values to `x` and `y`.

Comment: So the two goroutines are jammed until the tuple assignment is interpreted, where channel c output twice and form an implicit tuple. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Sends on unbuffered channel are blocked until there's a goroutine ready to receive from it.